# rails route a path as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

how to have 'something/like/this' route to any controller action with the whole 'something/like/this' as a string stored in params[:path]?

I tried

match ':path' => 'posts#index'

but clearly doesn't work.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? to have path somewhere in controller? If it is true then just use request.request_uri inside your controller to get relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Use * instead of :, and it will match all remaining parts.

rails guide
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
at 3.11 Route Globbing

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
match '*path' => 'posts#index'
```